# Send php variable to javascript Ajax in HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a HTML page with javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
  function voteCounter(messageID)
  {
    $.get("./_vote/counter_ajax.php?messageID="+messageID, function(data){
       alert(data);
    });
  } 
/* ]]> */  
</script>
```

My PHP file 'counter_ajax.php':

```
<?php

require "../lib/config.php";

$STB = $config['dbTableNames']['votes'];

$DBServer = $config['dbConnection']['host'];
$DBUser = $config['dbConnection']['user'];
$DBPass = $config['dbConnection']['pass'];
$DBName = $config['dbConnection']['name'];

$messageID = $_GET['messageID'];

$db = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

$resultUp = $db->query("SELECT SUM(voteUp) AS voteUp FROM $STB WHERE messageID = '$messageID'")->fetch_object()->voteUp;
$resultDown = $db->query("SELECT SUM(voteDown) AS voteDown FROM $STB WHERE messageID = '$messageID'")->fetch_object()->voteDown;

echo json_encode("Positive: " . $resultUp . " .... Negative: " . $resultDown);

?>
```

If I run PHP file in browser is working, the result is filled with text and variables:

> Positive: 3 .. Negative: 2

But the response in HTML in alert box is this, without variables:

> Positive:  .. Negative:

What is the right approach?

Comment: You are getting the response in JSON , so try alert(JSON.parse(data));

Comment: `alert(messageID);` and check if it is correct.

Comment: I've already  tried with `alert(JSON.parse(data))`. The same result, without variables.

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` To see all your returned json.

Comment: With `console.log(data);` I receive in Firebug in Firefox the result with variables: Positive: 3 .. Negative: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery Ajax functions are designed to identify the response type(html, json, xml etc.) according to the mine type/content type sent by server in header of response.

In your case you have not set any content type so JQuery function was unable to figure out the json response.

On PHP side you can do :

```
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

OR at jQuery side you can use **jQuery.getJSON()** that always assumes that server response is in json.

Also there is option in jQuery.get() to set the datatype in the fourth parameter like:

```
 jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your php output is json, data variable will be json object and alert will not convert data object to string. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
  function voteCounter(messageID)
  {
    $.get("./_vote/counter_ajax.php?messageID="+messageID, function(data){
       alert(data.Positive);
    });
  } 
/* ]]> */  
</script>
```

Here is relevant documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#example-5